# Is it legal to use another method for making payment on mobile app which is on App Store and Playstore?

Tags: ios, google-play-services, subscription, mobile-application

I'm from Côte d’Ivoire and I make a mobile app with react native where users pay for adding  profil they want to control. 
I want to give to my users the possibility to make theirs payment in my app but Apple doesn’t have the way of payment we use in my country ( Orange Money, Moov Money, Mtn Money, Wave, ..). So first, I want to know if it’s a case of Subscription or in-App purchased which are in the official documentation and second how can I do it? Can I implement myself theses system payements in my app ? Is it legal ?

I made a version where I used a webview to show my website of payement to users but I didn't submit it to AppStore or Playstore yet because I'm afraid that this update will be refused.

Comment: If you want app on AppStore you need to have an InAppPurchase using Apple Storekit.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload an app that charges users bypassing Apple it will either not pass review or be removed soon after. Even Epic Games had to take down Fortnite.

Comment: To be clear, Apple only requires the use of in-app purchases for things that will be used in the app or on the device. In-app purchases are not required for the purchase of physical goods.

Comment: But I saw that after Epic games episode's , developers have now authorization to use a link for redirecting theirs users to an external site to make their payements. can I use this solution too? or is it not yet available?